# Compare with the next element in foreach javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In my project I have to check for availability of time of a timetable, in a way to insert a button that should contains two values as text. The day starts at 8 and ends at 18, each day has its sessions. I have a JSON array that contains all the sessions of the day, and each session has a start hour and an end hour, so when I find any space of time I want to append a button to my html. This button will have some text (example : 8->10) with an `onClick` method that will take me to another function. Here is some code that I hope it can make my problem more understandable:

```
function evenement(id)
{
  $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/salle/evenement/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success : function(data)
        {     var start_date =8;
              var end_date =18;
              var buttons ="";
            data.forEach(function(element, index, array)
            {
                for (var i = start_date; i < end_date; i++) {
                      if (element.date_debut == i) {i=element.date_fin;}
                      if (element.date_debut != i) {buttons +="<button>"+i+"->"+element[index+1].date_fin+"</button>";}
                }

            }

            );
             $('.modal-title').text('Disponibilité');
        $('#corps').html(buttons);
      $('#groupe_modal').modal('show');

        },
      });

}
```

My problem is that I can't reach the next element while I'm working on the current one. The data is a parameter that I received in an ajax function and this code is just to make my self clear and I wrote it in a different section of my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `forEach` *callback* function takes 3 parameters, `function(element, index, array)`

```
`element`  The current element being processed in the array.
`index`    The index of the current element being processed in the array.
`array`    The array that forEach() is being applied to.
```

So if you add the second parameter to your function, which will be the index, then you can easily access next `data[index + 1]` (or previous `data[index - 1]`) item with it

> *Don't forget to properly check that you are not at the last (of first for previous) element when using it*

*Updated based on a question edit*

If you add the second *and* third parameter to your function, the `index` and the `array` the `forEach()` being applied to, then you can access next (or previous) item like this:

```
array[index + 1]     //next
array[index - 1]     //previous
```

```
function evenement(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/salle/evenement/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success : function(data)
        {   
            var start_date =8;
            var end_date =18;
            var buttons ="";
            data.forEach(function(element, index, array)
            {
                for (var i = start_date; i < end_date; i++) {
                      if (element.date_debut == i) {i=element.date_fin;}
                      if (element.date_debut != i) {buttons +="<button>"+i+"->"+array[index+1].date_fin+"</button>";}
                }
            });
            $('.modal-title').text('Disponibilité');
            $('#corps').html(buttons);
            $('#groupe_modal').modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Remember to check to see if you're on the last element and handle the non-existence of a 'next element' gracefully.

Comment: @SMcCrohan Of course that is needed, though found that not direct related since I didn't add the actual new code into the existing in any way

Comment: I need to access the next element , any propositions please

Comment: @Abid.Saifeddine I just showed you in my answer how to do that? ... using `data[index + 1]`

Comment: @Abid.Saifeddine Updated my answer a little. It should be `data[index+1]`, not `element[index+1]`